# Is Download Manager working on ARC?

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

My App relies on DownloadManager to work and I'm having a bad time trying to make it work on ARC.

I've enabled External Storage with metadata flag `enableExternalDirectory`, the app asked me at the start to choose the directory, but all downloads I enqueue fails with `ERROR_FILE_ERROR` which the documentation translates to "You are screwed".

Also logcat doesn't work for me. I enable adb, my adb-server connects to it but it stays quiet. The only way I'm able to debug is using:

```
plugin.shell('logcat -f /sdcard/logfile.txt');
```

**UPDATE:**
I fount this Fatal Error in the middle of the log:

```
F/DownloadManager(  212): Could not get ApplicationInfo for com.android.defconatiner
F/DownloadManager(  212): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.android.defcontainer
F/DownloadManager(  212):   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:281)
F/DownloadManager(  212):   at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider.onCreate(DownloadProvider.java:453)
F/DownloadManager(  212):   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1686)
F/DownloadManager(  212):   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1655)
F/DownloadManager(  212):   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5251)
F/DownloadManager(  212):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3400(ActivityThread.java:153)
F/DownloadManager(  212):   at android.app.ActivityThread$ProviderInstaller.run(ActivityThread.java:4795)
F/DownloadManager(  212):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
F/DownloadManager(  212):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
F/DownloadManager(  212):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
F/DownloadManager(  212):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Followed by several of this ones:

```
I/libposix_translation_static(  211): preopen: candidate: /data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/databases/downloads.db-journal
W/libposix_translation_static(  211): ASHMEM_SET_PROT_MASK: not implemented: fd=192, prot=3
W/libposix_translation_static(  211): ASHMEM_SET_PROT_MASK: not implemented: fd=192, prot=1
W/libposix_translation_static(  211): O_CLOEXEC is not supported
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Apparently there is an issue with DownloadProvider. I'll file a bug report.

```
W/DownloadManager(  211): [4] Stop requested with status FILE_ERROR: fstatvfs failed: ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
D/DownloadManager(  211): [4] Finished with status FILE_ERROR
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? i am also facing the same problem.